# SOQL relationship name syntax error

Tags: soql, relationships

I want to return the account name for each task in a SOQL query, am I correct in saying the relationship is that the Account is the parent object and the Task is the child object? I am not sure who to create my SOQL syntax to carry out this query, here is an example of what I have but I get a fail because the relationship `Accounts__r` doesn't seems to exist:

```
SELECT id, activitydate, accountid, (SELECT Name from Account__r) 
FROM task 
WHERE isrecurrence = false 
ORDER BY activity date ASC
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The name of relationship for the standard object and for the custom object is different.

1. **Standard object** ([List of all standard objects](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_list.htm))
   For standard objects like Account or Task the form of the relationship name is depending on the direction of the relationship:

   - Child-to-Parent

     > The relationship name to the parent
     >   is the name of the foreign key: 
     >   *SELECT Contact.FirstName, Contact.Account.Name from Contact*
   - Parent-to-Child

     > The parent object has a name for the child relationship that is unique
     >   to the parent, the plural of the child object name
2. **Custom object**

> When you use a relationship Name in a query, you must use the
>   relationship names without the __c. Instead, append an __r (underscore
>   underscore r)

So in your case you don't need to use `__r` because Account is a standard object.

To understand it better you can read more about relationships: [Understanding Relationship Names](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm?SearchType=Stem&Highlight=Understanding%7Cunderstand%7Cunderstanding%7C%7Crelationship%7CRelationship%7Crelationships%7CRelationships%7C%7CName%7Cname%7Cnames%7CNames%7Cnaming%7Cnamed%7CNAME)

Answer (score 2):

It should be this:

```
SELECT id, activitydate, accountid, Account.Name 
FROM task 
WHERE isrecurrence = false 
ORDER BY activity date ASC
```

The __r is for custom objects. Salesforce uses it's own names for standard Objects.
Also it is a master detail. There is only 1 account for an activity.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
[Select Id, Name,
    (Select Id, Subject from Tasks) 
    from Account]
```

or

```
Task[] tasksList = [SELECT Id, Subject, ActivityDate, Owner.Name FROM Task where accountid in ( SELECT id FROM Account)];
```

Comment: A bit more explanation would be great.